# Cannot add Spark-Java as a Maven project in Eclipse - Not an Archetype?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spark-java

Following this patchy tutorial here:

http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#getting-started

I added the following to a new archetype:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

After creating a new project and giving it a name I get the following error:

> Unable to create project from archetype [com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.2 -> ]
>   The defined artifact is not an archetype

There is no Repo URL given on the documentation, so it must be under the nexus?

Comment: Looking at the tutorial it does not provide or define an archetype.  It provides a maven dependency that is meant to be inserted into a pom.xml generated in an already created maven project.  As far as I know there is no general purpose maven archetype for spark projects.  However, for making it easy to setup a working demo there is a Spark Java Hello World Archetype for Maven at https://github.com/ImaginateWayne/sparkjava-archetypes/tree/master/sparkjava-helloworld-archetype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new maven project and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml file. When you're done it should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your-group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

That's it. You can now create a Java class like this:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

and run it :)